# Gradle include compiled Java classes as a module dependency

Tags: java, gradle, jar

I have been given a directory of compiled .class files in Java, which I must include as a dependency when building my JAR. I am building this JAR using Gradle. How do I include this directory as a dependency in Gradle?

Note: This is a directory that looks like 'com.example.projectname' with files like 'file1.class', 'file2.class', etc. I want these .class files to be in my JAR.

Comment: You could simply pack these `.class` files into a `.jar` file once and then always use this `.jar` file as a simple file dependency. Do these files change at all? Are they generated by another tool?

Comment: @lu.koerfer no, they are static. Making them into their own jar is a good idea. However, I am having trouble including them into my jar once I have made them into a jar. They need to show up alongside my custom files and I don't know Gradle well enough to figure that out yet(though I've tried a lot of things!)

Comment: A `.jar` file with dependencies included is called a *fat JAR* (or *uber JAR*). There are different ways to create such a jar, either [by just using Gradle or with a special plugin](http://www.baeldung.com/gradle-fat-jar).

Comment: The problem is that those are dependencies - I want to include these .class files as if they were my own generated ones. I tried putting them directly into the build classes directory and that worked temporarily, but I'm looking for a more permanent fix to that.

Comment: Well, the question is: Are they dependencies? Do they get referenced from your code? If you only want to include them into your JAR, just add the respective statement to your `jar` task configuration: `jar { from files(...) }` or `jar { from fileTree(...) }`.

Comment: Ah, that's what I was looking for, thanks! Would you like to answer the question officially so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add any files to the JAR file of your project by configuring the respective `jar` task (created by the `java` plugin) :

```
jar {
    from files('path/to/file.class', 'path/to/otherfile.class'
    // or
    from fileTree('path/to/dir') {
        include '**/*.class'
    }
}
```

Please note, that those classes are part of the classpath when using the JAR, but they won't be available when using an IDE, as Gradle does not know these files in its own understanding of either source sets (for compilation) or configurations (for dependencies).